# DateTime sorting for datatables

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm currently working on a datatable that displays content with dates. I have the table sorted descending on the date field of the datatable.

Here is the code:

```
var eventsTable = $("#eventsTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": '',
    "order": [0, "desc"],
    "columns": [
   { "data": "DateModified" },
   { "data": "Type" },
   { "data": "UserName" },
   { "data": "Description" },
   { "data": "Priority" }
    ]
});
```

However, the issue I'm having is it's not sorting the date/times properly. An example of what the date times look like ordered using this is:

```
18/11/2015 9:58:36 a.m.
18/11/2015 6:48:22 a.m.
18/11/2015 4:25:34 p.m.
18/11/2015 2:55:24 p.m.
18/11/2015 12:40:10 p.m.
```

As you can see that's not the correct order by date time. For some reason it's just getting the first number from the time and sorting it based on that. What can be done with this datatable so that it orders based on date/time.

Comment: Are you using DataTables.Net? If yes, you have to specify the type of the column in the "columns"

Comment: so something like this? { "data": "DateModified", "type": "date" }

Comment: can i ask why i got downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

So in the comments above someone has said to add a type date to the data column.

So i changed:

```
{ "data": "DateModified" }
```

to

```
{ "data": "DateModified", "type": "date" }
```

And now it sorts perfectly. Thanks for the help